# If I just want to determine a value is present, which Swift data structure should I use?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, language-agnostic, swift

I'm looking at a bunch of names, and I want to record all the names. My plan was to iterate over the array of names, and use a dictionary to keep track of each name, so I could just look up the name in the dictionary in O(1) time to see if it existed.

What would be the best data structure for this available in Swift? (I'd love to learn the name of the generic data structure that would be best for this, even if it's not in Swift.)

A `Dictionary` object would do fine, but it requires a value for the key, when I really only need the key.

Comment: You mean a HashSet or a HashMap or a HashTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a *Set* (a collection of unordered unique objects - some implementations are ordered, though).

Swift and ObjectiveC have [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), wouldn't this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not provide a set type. You can refer to [this blog post](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/08/creating-a-set-type-in-swift/) for how to define a Set.

Code reproduced here for quick reference:

```
struct Set<T: Hashable> {
    typealias Element = T
    private var contents: [Element: Bool]

    init() {
        self.contents = [Element: Bool]()
    }

    /// The number of elements in the Set.
    var count: Int { return contents.count }

    /// Returns `true` if the Set is empty.
    var isEmpty: Bool { return contents.isEmpty }

    /// The elements of the Set as an array.
    var elements: [Element] { return Array(self.contents.keys) }

    /// Returns `true` if the Set contains `element`.
    func contains(element: Element) -> Bool {
        return contents[element] ?? false
    }

    /// Add `newElements` to the Set.
    mutating func add(newElements: Element...) {
        newElements.map { self.contents[$0] = true }
    }

    /// Remove `element` from the Set.
    mutating func remove(element: Element) -> Element? {
        return contents.removeValueForKey(element) != nil ? element : nil
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can just use Dictionary and use the name as both key and value.

Comment: I would even use `[Element: ()]`